# cachedResponseForRequest not working on ios 9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlcache

I have an application which was working till ios 9.2 and now it suddenly stopped working since ios 9.3.
Issue is: cachedResponseForRequest is giving us values null if we do the following in webViewDidFinishLoad.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let cachedURLResponse = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest((webView.request)!)
}
```

The above line of code does work till ios 9.2 I did confirm.
What could be the potential issue here does anyone know ?

Comment: Are you sure your request is cacheable? Some sites aren't.

Comment: It is definitely cacheable since it worked till ios 9.2. The latest OS upgrade has caused issues in not getting cacheable.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue.

Comment: Im thinking the Cache methods are broken in 9.3 again. I have been having issues with this for sometime now. It just will either cache and won't ever delete it or never cache anything.

Comment: Yes MNM, I have opened a bug ticket for apple but havent got any response from them yet. They know its an issue on their side.

Comment: Can you share the bug ticket no. I am facing the same issue.